# Unity android project throws "Your hardware does not support this application sorry" error

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, fresco

I have been investigating for 2 days. I have read a lot of things. To summarize what I read:

- Non-NEON devices will not work with UNITY 5 builds.
- You should set your Install Location to "Automatic or Force Internal"
- You should set your Write Access to "Internal Only"

Along with the above ones, I also tried with these texture compression settings:

- Don't override
- DXT (Tegra)

Also there are two cases that I tried:

- When I built the game from UNITY and generate an apk. It worked fine on the phone.
- I selected "Google Android Project" and exported the unity project. After exporting, I got the /assets/bin/ folder and copy into my android project assets. With this option, it didn't work.

Phones that I tried are Sony Xperia M5 and One Plus 2. Both of them have ARM Cortex-A53 CPUs. Hence, the Non-NEON option is eliminated I think. I think that there should be another reason causing this problem.

By the way, the game works on both cases on s5, s6, s3 mini and Xperia Z1.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there anything else in the LogCat?

Comment: Seems kind of bizarre.  Can you simply **try with some other phones**, you must have a friend or relative on hand?

Comment: Could there be some ridiculous problem, like, you have forgot to set the Android to "developer mode"?  (Google that.)  We forget that all the time here!

Comment: @JoeBlow Yeap, I have tried on other devices like s5,s6,s3 mini, Xperia Z1. All of them worked. Really awkward. I should indicate this in the question by the way. Also "developer mode" is off.

Comment: @CaseB Both M5 and One Plus 2 are far away from me :( Those are the phones my friends with which I would like to test my game have, ironically.

Comment: @aod Are you using any plugin?

Comment: @Programmer in unity no. I don't know Android part. Android project is belong to another group of people. As soon as I learn, I will answer.

Comment: I will be gone for hours and will be back. Anyways make sure that Open GL is set to version 2 not 3, then test on One Plus 2 device. You can set this from Unity settings. If using Android Project, add `<uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" />` to the Manifest.

Comment: "Android project is belong to another group of people" ah, you're buggered  :)  I'd just forget about it - blame them.  Unity is used by millions and easily builds to and runs on pretty much all Androids. Don't waste another moment of your own time on it.

Comment: @Programmer Yes. `<uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" />`  settings was already done. Stiil no success :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A friend in the Android team found that native libraries missing after integration with `fresco` which is a powerful system for displaying images in Android applications. Also, there is an issue on the `fresco`'s github page: https://github.com/facebook/fresco/issues/361

In there, a man whose nickname is `kassim` says that "A common issue with native libs on Android is that if one native lib is available for an abi then all your native libs need to be available for that abi, it won't fall back to a lower supporting abi, so x86_64 won't fall back to x86".

He offers putting the code below into the android section of `build.gradle` file:

```
packagingOptions {
    exclude "lib/armeabi/libbitmaps.so"
    exclude "lib/armeabi/libgifimage.so"
    exclude "lib/armeabi/libimagepipeline.so"
    exclude "lib/armeabi/libmemchunk.so"
    exclude "lib/armeabi/libwebp.so"
    exclude "lib/armeabi/libwebpimage.so"
    exclude "lib/arm64-v8a/libbitmaps.so"
    exclude "lib/arm64-v8a/libgifimage.so"
    exclude "lib/arm64-v8a/libimagepipeline.so"
    exclude "lib/arm64-v8a/libmemchunk.so"
    exclude "lib/arm64-v8a/libwebp.so"
    exclude "lib/arm64-v8a/libwebpimage.so"
    exclude "lib/x86_64/libbitmaps.so"
    exclude "lib/x86_64/libgifimage.so"
    exclude "lib/x86_64/libimagepipeline.so"
    exclude "lib/x86_64/libmemchunk.so"
    exclude "lib/x86_64/libwebp.so"
    exclude "lib/x86_64/libwebpimage.so"
}
```

This solved the problem.

Comment: Another possibility is to add ndk { abiFilters "armeabi-v7a" } to build.gradle. (can also be abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86" if you are including Intel.