# Unity error, Failure to initialize! Your hardware does not support this application, sorry

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I created a simple AR application on Unity using Vuforia, the problem occurs 
when i try to launch custom UnityPlayerActivity

What i've done 
1) Make a build of project with this player settings:
    Install location: automatic
    i gave my package name
    and as a device filter chooced ARM7 + x86

So after i exported my project from Unity i need to get all unity files and unity scene and export it to another Android project 
i copied the next folder jniLibes and assets to application folder to another Android project, copied the needed Manifest properties and rebuild project

when i launch it on Samsung galaxy s5 it works fine but when i try do same on Samsung galaxy s6 or on Google Pixel with Android 7.1 on launch it gives me an error  "Failure to initialize! Your hardware does not support this application, sorry!"  but when i make build of exported Unity project on this devices everything works Fine, i spend already 3 days trying to solve this problem

Comment: This may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38529767/unity-android-project-throws-your-hardware-does-not-support-this-application-so